# NHibernate matching property as a substring

Tags: c#, nhibernate, substring

I'm trying to find the "best" way to match, for example, politicians' names in RSS articles. The names will be stored in a database accessed with NHibernate. As an example:

```
Id  Name
--- ---------------
1   David Cameron
2   George Osborne
3   Alistair Darling
```

At the time of writing, the BBC politics news RSS feed has an item with the description

> Backbench Conservative MPs put pressure on Chancellor George Osborne to stop rail firms in England increasing commuter fares by up to 11%.

For this article, I would like to detect that George Osborne is mentioned. I realise that there are several ways that this could be done, e.g. selecting all the politicians' names first, and comparing them in code, or doing the NHibernate equivalent of a LIKE.

The application itself would have a few dozen feeds, which will be queried at most every 15 minutes. Obviously there are speed, memory and scaling concerns, so I would like to ask for a recommended approach (and NHibernate query if relevant).

Comment: Will this query be performed at the DB or in memory? In mean, do you receive the feed, persist it and then query or can you query as soon as you download it?

Comment: I'm open to either approach. The feed will be going in the database at some point.

Comment: How often will the politicians list be updated? Not so often, I suppose. You can simply keep a list of politicians in memory and, for each downloaded feed entry, simply run a `foreach Name in Politicians FeedEntry.Content.Contains(Name)`.

Comment: They won't be added all that often - maybe more after initial go-live, but it will settle down quite soon. Nice approach - takes database querying out of the equation.

Comment: Indeed. You can use a simple expiration logic to refresh the politicians' list after some hours to make sure that it's updated. Or, better yet: if the politicians' entries ar only updated using your app, you can refresh the list after a successful write.

Comment: If you think of the SQL statement you will need to do this, I think you will find it hard to construct an effective query. I think @AndreCalil 's caching solution is the best bet - you can squeeze a lot of rows into your cache. You could also use e.g. Lucene.net to index to RSS articles (maybe just in-memory) and query the index instead. This will give you a relevance rating for each search result.

Comment: @AndreCalil I've implemented your approach, and it works well. If you want to collate your comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @harriyott There you go, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we were discussing on the comments, I believe that there is a simpler approach to this problem:

1. Keep a list of the politicians' in memory. Because these entities won't be updated often, it's safe to work like this. Just implement an expiration logic to refresh it from the database sooner or later.
2. For each downloaded feed entry, simply run `foreach Name in Politicians FeedEntry.Content.Contains(Name)` (or something like it) before saving the entry to the database.

There you go, no complex query needed and less I/O for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Along the following lines I would either use use a regex expression or a contains to get the politicians that match the feed.  The politician names and ids can be a simple collection in memory.

Then the the feed can be saved in a memcached or redis (even a db would do) with a guid.  Then save the associated guid in a table that holds politician_id, feed_guid.

For some statistics you can also have a table which is an aggregate of politician_id, num_articles_mentioned where the num_articles_mentioned is incremented by 1.

You can wrap the above in a transaction if needed.